# How do you show that the union of subsets is a basis of $A + B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am asking for hints and tips in solving this:

Let $H$ be a vector space.
For $U_1, U_2$ subsets of $H$, define $U_1 + U_2$ to be the set $\{u_1 + u_2\,|\,u_1 \in U_1 \wedge u_2 \in U_2\}$. Let $A$ and $B$ be subspaces of $H$.

Let $S_0$ be a basis for $A\cap B$.

Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be subsets of $H$ such that $S_0 \cup S_1$ and $S_0 \cup S_2$, $(i)$extend $S_0$ to a basis for $A$ and $B$, respectively. $(ii)$Show that $S_0 \cup S_1 \cup S_2$ is a basis for $A+B$.

My attempt:

Suppose on the contrary that $S_0 \cup S_1 \cup S_2$ is a linearly dependent subset of $A + B$. Then, there is a non trivial linear combination of vectors in $S_0 \cup S_1 \cup S_2$ whose sum is 0.
That is, there exists scalars $a_1, a_2, ..., a_k, b_1, b_2, ..., b_l, c_1, c_2, ..., c_m \in F$, not all zero, such that
\begin{align*}
        a_1p_1 +  ... + a_kp_k + b_1q_1  + ... + b_lq_l + c_1r_1 + ... + c_mr_m = 0
    \end{align*}
Case 1: If $a_1 = ... = a_k = 0$, then $q_1, ..., q_l, r_1, ..., r_m$ are linearly dependent.
Case 2: If $b_1 = ... = b_l = 0$, then $p_1, ..., p_k, r_1, ..., r_m$ are linearly dependent.
Case 3: If $c_1 = ... = c_m = 0$, then $p_1, ..., p_k, q_1, ..., q_l$ are linearly dependent.
If neither of the cases, then
\begin{align*}
        a_1p_1 + ... + a_kp_k + c_1r_1 + ... + c_mr_m &= -b_1q_1 - ... - b_lq_l\\
        a_1p_1 + ... + a_kp_k + b_1q_1 + ... + b_lq_l &= -c_1r_1 - ... - c_mr_m\\
        b_1q_1 + ... + b_lq_l + c_1r_1 + ... + c_mr_m &= -a_1p_1 - ... - a_kp_k
    \end{align*}
implies that
\begin{align*}
        p' = q' = r'
    \end{align*}
for some $p' \in P - \{0\},\,q'\in Q - \{0\},\, r' \in R - \{0\}$.
In each of the cases, we have a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, it is custom to post your own work, but since you ask for a hint, let me give you an idea:

It should be clear that $S_0 \cup S_1 \cup S_2$ spans $A+B$, so we just need to prove that it is a set of linearly independent vectors. Write

$S_0=\{s_0^1,...s_0^k\}$

$S_1=\{s_1^1,...s_1^n\}$

$S_2=\{s_2^1,...s_2^m\}$

Assume now for contradiction that we have a linear dependence

$\lambda_0^1s_0^1 + .... \lambda_2^ms_2^m = 0$

As the hint, put the $\lambda_2$'s on the right hand side, and arrive at contradictions if the righthand side is $0$ or not.

Comment: Hi, please check my post as I did what you said. Is it correct?